# Why is this happening in python? python if-else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

The below two if-else statements shows different results.

## 1

```
if value in twins:
    tmp = twins[value] + [box]
else:
    tmp = [box]
twins[value] = tmp
```

## 2

```
if value in twins:
    tmp = twins[value] + [box]
    twins[value] = tmp
else:
    tmp = [box]
    twins[value] = tmp
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: And where are the results being shown?

Comment: Those should be equivalent. And to `twins.setdefault(value, []).append(box)`

Comment: Include a sample where the results are different. I don't think they are! Except you have some code in between that changes the flow.

Comment: So those should be the same. Thank you!!